# Receive non HTTP requests in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, rtsp

I need to receive requests in Node JS that almost identical to HTTP requests, but have a different word to HTTP in the header for example the first line of the request is:

```
POST / RTSP/1.0
```

(instead of `POST / HTTP/1.0`)

The rest of the request format is identical to HTTP in every way.

Is there a way of making the http server parser ignore that the protocol is called HTTP in the first line of the request? So I can use http.createServer etc to receive and respond to these "non-HTTP" requests?

(I know I could use the net module rather than the http module, but then I'd have to implement the header parsing etc, all myself. )

Comment: ... so what exactly is your question?

Comment: @bguiz, basically, is there a way to make it ignore that it doesn't say HTTP in the header? (Without rewriting the http server for just one word difference)

Comment: If the server is indeed [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol), then your would need to write your own anyway.  Apart from that one word, if there is no difference in the rest of the content, then the right thing to do would be to alter the server to write HTTP instead of RTSP anyway, plus it would be a whole lot easier too. I'm assuming that you ask this because you do not have access to the server?

Comment: I have no control over the client code (iOS and iTunes Airplay) which sends these POST requests as RTSP instead of HTTP. (according to wikipedia RTSP has no POST method, so it's HTTP)

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up server and client in my comment above. Unfortunately this leaves your in a pickle. I don't know the answer to this - perhaps someone else on this site can can help you!

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way would be to implement tcp server in node that acts as a proxy replacing initial POST:

( note: I haven't tested this code, but it should be good enough to illustrate idea)

```
var net = require('net');

net.createServer(function(s)
{
    var sawRequest = false;
    var buff = "";
    var requestText = "";
    var connected = false;
    var cli = net.createConnection(yourHttpServerPort);
    s.on('data', function(d) {
        if (!sawRequest) {
           requestText += d.toString();
           if (requestText.match(/POST \/ RTSP\/1.0/)) {
              requestText.replace('POST / RTSP/1.0', 'POST / HTTP/1.0');
              buff = requestText;
              sawRequest = true;
           } 
        } else {
           buff += d.toString();
        }
        if (connected)
        {
           if (buff != '')
             cli.write(buff);
           cli.write(d);
        } else {
           buff += d.toString();
        }
    });
    cli.once('connect', function() {
        connected = true;
        cli.write(buff);
    });
    cli.pipe(s);

}).listen(publicFacingRTSPport);
```

You could probably do the same with HAProxy

Comment: I would do the same, but use a Transform stream between the client connection and the downstream server and do the regex there...

Comment: I actually re-used here my old portforward.js script that is older than streams2 :)

Comment: Missed one of the parentheses: `if (requestText.match(/POST \/ RTSP\/1.0/) {` should be `if (requestText.match(/POST \/ RTSP\/1.0/)) {`